# How to create a multidimensional matrix in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I am a beginner in Python.
I want to create the matrix below, how should I create it?

```
[
    [0,1], [0,2], [0,3],
    [1,1], [1,2], [1,3],
    [2,1], [2,2], [2,3],
    [3,1], [3,2], [3,3]
]
```

I looked up numpy, maybe I'm not looking in the right way, I didn't find any good way.

Comment: What you have typed there will create a two dimensional matrix, 12 rows and 2 columns.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. When you use the code that you already have, what result do you get? How is that different from what you want? What result **do** you want? And **why** do you want to create the "matrix"? What will you *do with it*? If you are not familiar with the language fundamentals, you should follow a tutorial all the way through before trying to work with advanced third-party libraries like Numpy.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost what `numpy.ndindex` is doing, except you want one of the values to start with `1`. You can fix it by converting to array and adding `1`:

```
np.array(list(np.ndindex(4,3)))+[0,1]
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [0, 3],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 3],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [3, 1],
       [3, 2],
       [3, 3]])
```

Comment: Thanks, numpy is so simple!
I'll have to go read the documentation again.

Answer (score 0):

A rather simple list comprehension will generate this data structure. Numpy not required.

```
[[x, y] for x in range(4) for y in range(1, 4)]
```

Result:

```
[[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], 
 [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], 
 [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], 
 [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3]]
```

Comment: I just quite simply wanted to practice creating two-dimensional matrices. I never understood it properly, and after reading your code I understood it instantly.
Thank you, it solved my primary problem.